# Is there a way to automatically indent a parenthesis in Slime REPL after pressing `C-m o`?

Tags: indentation, newlines, repl, slime

I am using Slime, Paredit, and SBCL to code in Common Lisp. While editing a `.lisp` file, suppose I have this code:

```
(dotimes (i 4))
```

I will represent the cursor (point) as -!-. Having the cursor in this position and pressing `return` key I get:

```
(dotimes (i 4) -!-)

;;; press `return`

(dotime (i 4) 
      -!-)
```

I would like to have the same in the SLIME Repl. There, if I have:

```
CL-USER> (dotimes (i 4)-!-)

;; after pressing `return` the expression is evalued

NIL
```

I can use `C-o`. However, `C-o` gives a new line but with no indentation, such as:

```
CL-USER> CL-USER> (dotimes (i 4)-!-)

;; after pressing `C-o`, I have:

CL-USER> CL-USER> (dotimes (i 4)
-!-)
```

Is there a way to get a new line but with a properly indented parenthesis?  Another command maybe? Should I insert something on my init files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-j` runs `slime-repl-newline-and-indent` which I think will work. Whenever I'm faced with an unfamiliar mode, I do `C-h m` which shows me mode information, including the keymaps: I can then zero in on the relevant function(s). That's how I found this.

The doc string of `slime-repl-newline-and-indent` says:

> Insert a newline, then indent the next line.
> Restrict the buffer from the prompt for indentation, to avoid being
> confused by strange characters (like unmatched quotes) appearing
> earlier in the buffer.